# No audio being recorded from OBS Studio

Tags: audio, obs-studio

I can see the mic's working in Windows settings and they work in tools like Zoom or Google Meet. So I can rule out the device not working or human error like the device not being plugged in.

The video records, but the sound doesn't. BUT it used to. I don't really know why it happened but I can't seem to find anything to fix.

The soundbars move for the speakers source. But for any of the mic input sources they do not work.

Main audio is Realtek, AMD CPU, Nvidia GPU

Things I've tried:

- Uninstalling and reinstalling OBS Checking the windows volume mixer
- Settings > Output > Recording > Encoder to different settings. It's
  currently on NVIDIA NVENC H.264
- Settings > Output > Recording - Changing rate control from lossless to CBR
- Settings > Output > Audio - changed all Audio bitrates to 320 except track 1 which is 160
- Settings > Audio > Global Audio Devices - set all to disabled
- Audio Mixer > Advanced Audio Properties - all sources say status is
  "active"
- Audio Mixer > Advanced Audio Properties - All audio sources
  are set to track 1. Then each audio source is set to their own
  individual track e.g. headset is track 2, mic above screen is track
  3, speakers are track 4
- Audio Mixer > Advanced Audio Properties - increase volume to 20dB
- Audio Mixer > Individual audio source > filter - set a gain filter to 20dB Delete the source from the scene
- add a new source creating from scratch not adding an existing.
- checked windows privacy settings for mic access,
- configured each OBS input specifically rather than relying on "Default"
- disallowed apps to claim 100% control of audio devices(in audio settings)
- configured each OBS input specifically rather than relying on "Default"
- Restarting OBS
- Restarting Windows
- Checking all drivers for windows /    sound devices
- Turned off BitDefender (my antivirus) and tested it but not joy.

I went to Windows Event Viewer and the only event which was a "warning" was this:

```
The machine-default permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
{C2F03A33-21F5-47FA-B4BB-156362A2F239}
 and APPID 
{316CDED5-E4AE-4B15-9113-7055D84DCC97}
 to the user EOIN-RYZEN\Eoin SID (S-1-5-21-690287034-1867903814-1615486827-1001) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Microsoft.Windows.ShellExperienceHost_10.0.19041.1949_neutral_neutral_cw5n1h2txyewy SID (S-1-15-2-155514346-2573954481-755741238-1654018636-1233331829-3075935687-2861478708). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.
```

I'm not sure what this means so I don't know whether to change anything.  When I checked the properties of OBS and then the security tab > Advanced I see my user is not the owner but "administrators" are.

https://obsproject.com/logs/tLnsu6Cac9BIb8s0

Comment: In addition, OP has checked windows privacy settings for mic access, disallowed apps to claim 100% control of audio devices(in audio settings), configured each OBS input specifically rather than relying on "Default".  He can see audio in through "Desktop Audio" input but nothing from several mics(web cam, usb mic, headset).  Desktop audio does appear to be very low for system. Main audio is Realtek, AMD CPU, Nvidia GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I could swear I have done this before, I deleted the audio input sources from all scenes, then I readded it again.  That worked.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working!

Comment: Me too, it was a disruptive 6 months of not having it.

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the error "Max audio buffering reached!" at the buttom - Have you changed the fps-recording? Can you try to set it to 30fps, for example? ( Either at the camera settigns or the entire scene's )

Also, try to untic "Use custom audio device" under the camera settings ( according to this: https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/max-audio-buffering-on-audio-source-thats-disabled-help.140344/ )

***Edit:*** I also saw a recommendation for *disabling "Use Device Timestamps" on the desktop audio source properties*.

If the issue persists - have you added any hardware lately or changed any other setting that might interfere? Maybe installed some new antivirus software or something like that? I saw some complaints about Elgato product that cause this problem.

Comment: Thanks @netan.  I don't have "use device timestamps" ticked for anything.  I have the mic disabled in Windows for the webcam.  I also checked and the "use custom audio device" is not ticked for webcam.  I do see an option "audio output mode" which has the options "capture audio only"  output desktop sound (DirectSound), output desktop sound (WaveOut).  On the webcam if I change Resolutoin/FPS type to custom I can change FPS to either Match Output FPS or Highest FPS.  I couldn't see any audio options in the scene.

Comment: I don't have Elgato I have Bit Defender, I wonder if that would be it.

Comment: I honestly don't think so but you could try to disable BitDefender and see if it helps. If so, then you should add OBS to it's exclutions.    I saw many people asking about the problem and many of them had different resolutions, then I think that the best way would be trying to run the PC without any other app in the background and without any other devices ( or even plug-ins in OBS... ). just disable everything and try recording again? Also - try to look for errors in Windows Event Viewer under "system" or "application" within the exact time of a recording.

Comment: I have now tried disabling BitDefender and it wasn't that, so I guess I can rule that out.

Comment: I wrote so many things. What about the rest? also: Try to disable other apps or seing if there are any error events? Can Windows see the microphone usage? Does OBS have permissions to access said microphone?

Comment: I tried using Windows Event Viewer, I added what I found to my question.

Comment: I tried shutting down nearly everything that was open and a few things in the task bar but that didn't make a difference.  OBS has permission to access the mic I believe.  I tried removing and readding it, and also reinstalling OBS.  It was working previously when it must have had permission, but I'm guessing something somewhere has changed.  I'm starting to wonder if it's because my Logitec Cam has a mic.  But I've disabled the mic and there is no web cam in the scene I'm testing with.  Mic works with other programs.